# Nav bar background not displaying correctly and menu not drop down on click

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make my navbar background appear white on all screens. What could be prohibiting this from happening?I change the css to !important on default and it displays correctly only on wide. I have tried adding a media query at the small and medium screen size and no luck. Also, my menu is dropping down.

```css
.navbar-default {
    background-color:white  !important;
    border-color: white  !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"  aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src=".png" alt=""/>&#160;<span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-1-0 ms-rteFontSize-4 ms-rteFontFace-5"></span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">site1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">site2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Site 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Site 4</a></li></ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following--

1. add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`
2. Use `data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"`.
3. Don't use `!important` rather use a id and style it.
4. Add custom css after bootstrap css.

**Working snippet**

```css
#mynav {
    background-color:white;
    border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav id="mynav" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"  aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src=".png" alt=""/>&#160;<span class="ms-rteThemeForeColor-1-0 ms-rteFontSize-4 ms-rteFontFace-5"></span></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">site1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">site2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Site 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Site 4</a></li></ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is there a way to keep this form pushing the content down, while its on small screen?

Comment: Use navbar-fixed-top class with your nav tag.